# Removing access of a particular model from a particular user in Django admin, but user is from a group having the access for that model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-authentication

Suppose user1 is a staff member belonging to a group g1 in django admin. This group g1 is having access to say a model m1. Now I want to remove the access of m1 model from user1 without removing him from the group g1.
How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing it in the code seems to be hackish. It is better to create another group `g2`, add there `user1` and delete him/her from `g1`. This is the only Django way I know.